# Ansible hostvars[''variable_holder'']" is undefined

Tags: ansible, undefined, hostvars

My Pipeline throws the following error:

```
TASK [microstrategy.mstrpax_configure : Get Project Names from Rest API] ***
skipping: [] => changed=false 
  false_condition: mstr_role in ("webserver")
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False

TASK [microstrategy.mstrpax_configure : Configure Telemetry Logging] ***
fatal: []: FAILED! => 
  msg: '"hostvars[''variable_holder'']" is undefined. "hostvars[''variable_holder'']" is undefined'
```

My Questions are.

- Why Ansible tells me that the `hostvars[''variable_holder'']` is undefined'?
- How can I fix that?
- How can I hand over variables from one hostgroup ("webserver") to another hostgroup ("iserver")?

In my playbook (`mstrpax_configure_tasks.yml`) I have during my run set conditions to skip some tasks when the condition is not true.

So far so good...but my task which where skipped, I set during the run inside the task before (`mstrpax_projects_loaded.yml`) over `set_fact` a hostvars variable.

```yaml
- name: 'Get Project Names from Rest API'
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: mstrpax_projects_loaded.yml
      when: 'mstr_role in ("webserver")'
```

In `mstrpax_projects_loaded.yml` "variable_holder" will be set during the run. But only inside the Hostgroup "webserver".

```yaml
- name: 'Register mstr_api_projnames_loaded Var'
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    mstr_api_projnames_output: '{{ mstr_api_projnames_loaded }}'

- name: 'Add Variable to Dummy Host'
  ansible.builtin.add_host:
    name: 'variable_holder'
    mstr_api_projnames_output: '{{ mstr_api_projnames_output }}'
```

Variable `hostvars['variable_holder']` will be used down below. But for the Hostgroup "iserver"

```yaml
- name: 'Enable Telemetry Logging'
  block:

    - name: 'Configure Telemetry Logging'
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: mstrpax_telemetry_logging.yml
      loop: "{{ hostvars['variable_holder']['mstr_api_projnames_output'].json | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: mstr_projects
      when: 'mstr_role in ("iserver")'
```

Note the Mapping of that "Hostgroups" will handled over ansible. That means Servers get a specified Tag "Role" which will be mapped then inside that Variable "_mstr_appcode2role"
The tasks will only be executed when a hostname pattern matches to the setted Tag "role" inside Terraform.

```yaml
mstr_role: '{{ tf_host["role"] }}'

# appcode to role mapping
_mstr_appcode2role:
  mstr: 'iserver'
  mstrweb: 'webserver'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept the suggested edits of formatting from me because without them it's hard to understand your question. After that, please add your inventory and the full code of your playbook, or at least full code of plays that are affected. Without that, it's not possible to help because we need to understand where the tasks are running. Actually, I already suspect where your issue is, but creating new variables that are just equal to already existing ones, as well as adding new hosts to store variables don't seem like a correct way to solve problems.

Comment: I know it's not a proper solution to store values during a run inside a "dummy_host". But trust me I tried a "normal" variable declaration to store the values but that dosen't work. Because of these hostgroup conditions "when: 'mstr_role in ("webserver")'",  when: 'mstr_role in ("iserver")'. For Ansible the variables for a specific hostgroup like 'webserver'  are only valid for that kind of hostgroup and it's not possible to get the values outside of that task to use that for the hostgroup 'iserver'. Only for my understanding over set fact and store them temporary to a 'dummy_host'

Comment: Please add the details on the groups to the question, not to the comments. By the way, you almost understood the cause of your problem by yourself.